# System Administrator Appreciation Day

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Just thought that today (in South Africa, your time zone may vary) is System Administrator Appreciation Day.

Would be nice to see a little banner or pop up on ServerFault saying thanks to the hard working IT Pros... or maybe having SF is enough appreciation.

Answer (score 4):

great idea! doing it now!